# Best Practice to run python script with multiple variations of config script

Tags: python, config

I am regularly running into the following situation: I have a script `config.py` that holds various parameters. I then run another `script.py` that imports the parameters from the `config.py` and performs some operations. At some point I wish to run `script.py` with multiple variations of `config.py`. My current approach is to transform `script.py` into a function and apply it to each desired parameter combination. For that I need to create another script `map_script.py` which adds boilerplate code.

Minimal Example for Illustration:

**config.py**

```
PARAMETER = 1
```

**script.py**

```
import config as conf
print(conf.PARAMETER**2)
```

**map_script.py**

```
desired_configurations = [1,2,3]
def map_function(PARAMETER):
    print(PARAMETER**2)

for PARAMETER in desired_configurations:
    map_function(PARAMETER)
```

I would be interested in the most elegant way to handle this given that such a config.py and script.py already exist. Furthermore I would be interested if it is considered best practice to set it up this way or if one should e.g. aim to formulate the script.py as a function in the first place.

Edit: I want to vary a certain subset of the parameters in the config file. So creating a separate config file for each combination seems also to cumbersome

Comment: You could replace `import config as conf` with `conf = importlib.import_module('config')`, so that the configfile's name becomes a variable.

Comment: By the way, your question seems to ask about different *config files*, but your example shows different *config scenarios* stored in a list (which is already a design choice of your config data).  Maybe you could clarify (the question or test, whichever is relevant).

Comment: done. As described creating a config file for each config scenario would be to cumbersome for my use case

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason, don't use Python modules as configuration files.

Comment: Is script.py a module? in which case it should contain  functions and maybe an `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` block. Or is it the main program of your package?  `map_script.py` should (imho) look like `import script; ... ; for p in desired_configurations:   script.its_function(p)`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to have a file **config.json** file containing all your parameter choices. Here is an example:

```
{"desired_configurations": [1,2,3]}
```

and then a single **script.pt** like this:

```
import json
desired_configurations = json.load(open('config.json', 'r'))['desired_configurations']

def map_function(PARAMETER):
    print(PARAMETER**2)


for PARAMETER in desired_configurations:
    map_function(PARAMETER)
```